# Can a UISearchController be used in a child view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm attempting to recreate a UI similar to that of the one found in the Maps app—namely my focus is on the bottom drawer. I've created a container view controller `DrawerViewController` that is added to the root view controller `ViewController`. The `DrawerViewController` handles the positioning and interaction with the drawer itself, which then receives a child view controller as its content—in this case, by default, `MapSearchViewController`. I'm trying to add a `UISearchController` to the `MapSearchController`, which simply contains the `UISearchBar` from the search controller and a `UITableView`. I'm having the issue that when the search bar is tapped, both the search bar and table view are disappearing, and from the UI inspector, I can see a `UITransitionView` has been added.

After some extensive research, I was able to find quite a few SO answers where although the situation wasn't the exact same, the general trend among them was that `definesPresentationContext` must be `true` on the view controller containing the search controller. I added this, but alas, no dice. This did however, lead me to a temporary solution: in the `DrawerViewController`, I had been adding the `MapSearchViewController` as a child by doing:

```swift
let mapSearchViewController = MapSearchViewController()
contentView.addSubview(mapSearchViewController.view)
addChild(mapSearchViewController)
mapSearchViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

I found that by removing the `addChild(_:)` call fixes the issue of the search bar and table view disappearing when the search bar is tapped, but since the view controller hasn't been added as a child, all of the logic in the `MapSearchViewController` doesn't get executed. I assume its an issue with the view controller hierarchy as such or how I'm trying to add the search controller to the `MapSearchController`, but I have no idea what to even begin to look for to fix this.

```swift
import UIKit

class MapSearchViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: MapSearchViewControllerDelegate?
    var searchController: UISearchController!
    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        definesPresentationContext = true

        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a building or place"
        view.addSubview(searchBar)

        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 2.0),
            searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -2.0),
            searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56.0)
        ])

        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 / 3.0
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchBar.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}

// Both these extensions just have protocol stubs as of now, but I'm including them to show they exist.
extension MapSearchViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    ...
}

extension MapSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    ...
}
```

I've foregone including the source for the `DrawerViewController` here, as I believe the only relevant part is the section included above where the `MapSearchViewController` is created and added. I haven't changed any properties of the `DrawerViewController` itself, only properties of the drawer's view. However, if anyone thinks they might know the issue and need to see the source, please leave me a comment and I can edit the question to include it.